# "return is not allowed here" when returning inside a kotlin lambda

Tags: android, kotlin, functional-programming

I use a lambda to handle callbacks from an asynchronous call. I'd like to define the callback outside the calling method to avoid a bulky method, but I can't seem to use early returns within the lambda, which makes the code unnecessarily difficult to read.

I've tried defining the lambda as a variable but returns are not viable inside the lambda.

I've tried defining the lambda inside a function and returning but returns were not viable there either.

For example:

```
 private fun onDataUpdated(): (Resource<List<Int>>) -> Unit =  {
   if (it.data.isNullOrEmpty()) {          
     // Handle no data callback and return early.
     return@onDataUpdated // This is not allowed   
    }

   // Handle the data update
   }
 }
```

I've also tried:

```
 private val onDataUpdated: (Resource<List<Int>>) -> Unit =  {
   if (it.data.isNullOrEmpty()) {          
     // Handle no data callback and return early.
     return // This is not allowed   
    }

   // Handle the data update
   }
 }
```

I'd like to perform an early return instead of using an else case, to avoid unnecessary indent, but I can't seem to find a way to use returns inside a lambda.

Comment: See my answer here: stackoverflow.com/a/74740489/9585130

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by labelling the lambda. For example, if you label it with `dataUpdated`:

```
private val onDataUpdated: (Resource<List<Int>>) -> Unit = dataUpdated@ {
    if (it.data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        // Handle no data callback and return early.
        return@dataUpdated
    }

    // Handle the data update
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'll just put the "return" at the bottom of the lambda. Here's an example using Dispatchers.IO:

```
var res = async(Dispatchers.IO){
   var text : String? = null
   if(channel==null) {
      text = networkRequest(url)
   }
   text
}.await()
```